# Puzzling behavior with Python 3 generators

Tags: python-3.x

The following two Python 3 code snippets differ by a change that I thought would make no difference. However, when run from IDLE in Python 3.5 under Mac OS X, they produce different results. I restarted the Python shell before running each snippet.

Snippet 1:

```
## The following prints [5, 7] as expected
a = (k for k in range(2, 10))    # generator for [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
p = next(a)                      # p is 2
a = (k for k in a if k % p != 0) # remove multiples of 2: generator for [3, 5, 7, 9]
q = next(a)                      # q is 3
a = (k for k in a if k % q != 0) # remove multiples of 3: generator for [5, 7]
print(list(a))                   # prints [5, 7]
```

Snippet 2: [The only difference is using *p* instead of *q* on the fourth and fifth lines of code.]

```
## The following prints [4, 5, 7, 8]
a = (k for k in range(2, 10))
p = next(a)
a = (k for k in a if k % p != 0)
p = next(a)                      # Using p instead of q
a = (k for k in a if k % p != 0) # Ditto
print(list(a))                   # prints [4, 5, 7, 8]
```

So it seems that reusing the object name *p* has far-reaching effects.

What am I missing? I tried without success to make the example significantly smaller.

Comment: This is a dup of previous questions (not super-easy to find, I admit) -- the generator expressions pick up the value of `p` *when they're used*, not at the time of definition.  There should be something around here under "late binding generator expressions" or something..

Comment: A shorter example is `p = 2 ; a = (k for k in range(2, 10) if k % p == 0) ; p = 3 ; print(list(a))` which prints `3, 6, 9`. The value of `p` isn't used until the generator is executed (when converted to a list).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The catch lies in the following two lines:

```
a = (k for k in a if k % p != 0)
p = next(a)                      # Using p instead of q
```

The "new `a`" yields those elements from "old `a`" that match the condition `k % p != 0`. However, that condition is only evaluated *at the time a new element is requested* from the generator `a`, and it uses the value `p` has then. In your case, that would be **3** (and *not* 2 anymore, as one might expect).

---

**Longer explanation:**

Let's trace what is going on in the code. I used three different `a` variables (`a`, `a2` and `a3`) to avoid confusion.

```
a = (k for k in range(2, 10))
```

A generator `a` is created, and `list(a)` would result in `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` at this point.

```
p = next(a)
```

The first value is consumed from `a` and assigned to variable `p`. `p` becomes `2`, and `list(a)` would result in [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] at this point.

```
a2 = (k for k in a if k % p != 0)
```

A new generator is created. It generates all values yielded by `a` that match the condition `k % p != 0`. Since `p` currently equals `2`, `list(a2)` would result in `[3, 5, 7, 9]` (BTW, generator `a` would be also be exhausted in the process).

```
p = next(a2)
```

A new value is requested from the generator `a2`. The latter requests a value from `a`, gets `3`, and checks if it matches the aforementioned condition `k % p != 0`. Since `p` currently equals `2`, it indeed does, and `a2` yields `3`, which becomes the new value of `p`.

Since one value was consumed from `a`, `list(a)` would result in `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` at this point. However, `list(a2)` would now result in `[4, 5, 7, 8]`! That's because `k % p != 0` would use the current value of `p`, which is `3`, making `a2` to skip the values `6` and `9`.

```
a3 = (k for k in a2 if k % p != 0)
```

A new generator `a3` is essentially the same as `a2`, because they both have the same condition.

```
print(list(a3))
```

The generator `a3` is exhausted, which in turn exhausts `a2`, which exhausts the values from `a`, resulting in the observed result `[4, 5, 7, 8]`.

Here, `a` yielded `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, but multiples of `3` have been filtered out by `a2`, and `a3` did not filter anything else (because it's basically the same as `a2`).

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear. Is there a simple way to "freeze" the values in a generator to what they are when the generator is defined, rather than when it is used? Or is this a bad idea?

Comment: The only thing you need to assure is that the variables used in the generator are not modified (`p` in your case). The first snippet you posted already avoids this problem altogether, because it uses a different variable, i.e. `q`. Another option would be to to create a function that creates a generator for you, using its own local `p` variable: `def make_gen(gen, p): return (k for k in gen if k % p != 0)`, and then `p = 2; a2 = make_gen(a, p)`. Subsequent modifications of `p` will not affect `a2`, because the latter will use a local `p` variable.

Comment: I run into the same issue as I expect the generator creates closure for the condition so the "p" gets remembered in its context. This behavior is very unexpected.
Thank you for the workaround with the function.